# Reading an argument list with a glob from a file

Tags: bash, unix, xargs, glob

I am trying to read arguments of `ll` command from file.
I have file `args.txt` with content `some?`. I have files with names `some1`, `some2` and `some3` and some other files. when I execute `cat args.txt | ll` I get the same result as when I execute `ll`.

Can someone explain me why is that and how can I achieve the desired result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DPM, BTW, `ll` isn't actually a UNIX command that exists. Out-of-the-box on several systems it's an *alias*, but an alias isn't a real command -- it's just an instruction to the shell to replace a prefix with a different string before interpreting a command; programs that aren't shells (and `xargs` is such a program) don't recognize aliases and can't run them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Note: I'm assuming that `ll` is an *alias* for `ls -l` or some variation.

As Charles Duffy points out, (by default) only *interactive shells* know about aliases, and scripts as well as tools such as `xargs` are unaware of them.</sup>

What you send through a pipeline to a command is received via its *stdin* stream, which is distinct from a command's *arguments* (options such as `-l` and operands such as `some?`).

Therefore, **an explicit transformation is needed to convert the contents of file `args.txt` to an *argument*** you can pass to `ls -l`:

```
ls -l $(cat args.txt)   # In Bash you can simplify to: ls -l $(< args.txt)
```

Note that the command substitution (`$(...)`) is deliberately *unquoted* so as to ensure that *globbing* (filename expansion) is applied to the contents of `args.txt`, as desired.

Yours is a rare case where this technique - which is **brittle** - is actually *needed*.

To illustrate the brittleness: If your globbing pattern were `"some file"?`, for instance (you'd need the double quotes for the pattern to still be recognized as a single argument), the command wouldn't work anymore, because the `"` characters lose their syntactic function when they're the result of a command substitution (or variable expansion).

---

The **standard utility for transforming stdin or file content into arguments is `xargs`**. However, **in your particular case it is *not* an option**, because your file contains a *glob* (filename pattern) that must be *expanded by the shell*, but `xargs` only invokes external utilities, without involving a shell:

```
$ xargs ls -l < args.txt # !! Does NOT work as intended here.
ls: file?: No such file or directory
```

Filename `file?` was passed *literally* to `ls` (and no file actually named `file?` exists) - no globbing happened, because no shell was involved.

Answer (score 3):

The following is somewhat overkill, but goes to pains to be correct and consistent regardless of shell configuration, and to work with all possible filenames (even those with whitespace):

```
# note f() ( ) instead of f() { }; this runs in a subshell, so its changes to IFS or
# shopt settings don't modify behavior of the larger shell.
globfiles() (
  set +f                      ## ensure that globbing is enabled
  shopt -u nullglob failglob  ## ensure that non-default options on how to handle failed
                              ## ...glob attempts are both disabled
  IFS=                        ## disable string-splitting
  while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
    printf '%s\0' $filename   ## unquoted use -> expand as glob
                              ## ...expands format string once per argument, hence once per
                              ## ...file found. (No string-splitting due to prior IFS=)
  done
)
```

...thereafter used as (if your input file is newline-delimited):

```
tr '\n' '\0' <args.txt | globfiles | xargs -0 ls -l --
```

...or (if your input file is NUL-delimited -- which is ideal, as this permits filenames containing literal newlines to be referenced):

```
globfiles <args.0sv | xargs -0 ls -l --
```

Comment: Wonders if it would work with `rc`?... If so Tom Duff would likely be proud; I'm thinking there might be some distant relation between you two perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` to pass the output of cat to the command (`ll` in your case):

```
cat args.txt | xargs ll
```

If your args.txt contains multiple values, separated by new line or space, `xargs` will pass each value separately, executing the command as many times, as entries in your args.txt:

For example, if your args.txt has this content:

```
/var/
/usr/
/usr /var
```

Then the results of execution will look like this:

```
$ cat args.txt | xargs ls
/usr:
bin  etc  games  include  lib  lib64  libexec  local  sbin  share  src  tmp

/usr/:
bin  etc  games  include  lib  lib64  libexec  local  sbin  share  src  tmp

/var:
adm  cache  crash  cvs  db  empty  games  gopher  kerberos  lib  local  lock  log  mail  nis  opt  preserve  run  spool  tmp  var  yp

/var/:
adm  cache  crash  cvs  db  empty  games  gopher  kerberos  lib  local  lock  log  mail  nis  opt  preserve  run  spool  tmp  var  yp
```

Comment: Note that by default, `xargs` gathers as many arguments as will conveniently fit on one line, so it normally executes the command many fewer times than there are entries in the input.  There are ways to force it to execute one command per argument.  This also runs foul of file names with spaces in them.

Comment: If `ll` is an alias, then `xargs ll` is unlikely to work.